# How to preserve time-series information for kalman-filtering with dlmModReg

Tags: r, kalman-filter

Here is a sample of my data I use.

[image]

I first fit this data into the a linear model, and then into a dlmModReg model (after calculating dV,dW, m0, C0).

```
model<-lm(Y1~X1[,1]+X1[,2])
model<-dlmModReg(X1,dV=a,dW=b,m0=c,C0=matrix(d,3,3,byrow=T))
```

where Y1 is "Discharge", X1 contains "rain_102" and "rain_111". Then I proceed to do the Kalman filtering on this data

```
filtermod <- dlmFilter(Y1, model)
```

and proceed to graph it

```
plot(Y1, type = "o", col = "seagreen")
lines(dropFirst(filtermod$m), type = "o", pch = 20, col = "brown")
```

[image]

As expected, the prediction does not contain any timeseries information. My question is where does the timeseries "dt.tm" data go to ensure I get the correct Kalman Filtering graphs and predictions.

I tried including the "dt.tm" variable in Y1 and X1; however, I get errors.